# Node.js: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am kinda new to Node JS. I get an error with my callback. This is my code:

```
var list=['382813587410259968','881413399304863744'];
var content=[];
var dataj;
list.forEach(function(value,callback){
Twitter.get('statuses/oembed', { id:value},  function (err, data, response) {
if(err)
{callback(err,null,null);}
dataj=data.html.toString;
callback(null,dataj,null);
        });
function func(dataj)
{
content.push(dataj);
console.log(content);
}
});
```

The callback(null,data,null) returns error. I would be very glad if you could help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with  line

list.forEach(function(value,callback)

No need to pass value. It is available internally.

For Demo Try following code snippet

```
   var list=['382813587410259968','881413399304863744'];      
   function callback(item, index) {
      console.log("index[" + index + "]: " + item );
   }
   list.forEach(callback);
```

You can also refer following link for more clarity

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_foreach

Comment: @sanaz .. please let me know in case of any query